# How can I remove pod links from a specific target in a post_install hook?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

**Background**

1. Had an existing iOS app using CocoaPods for all dependency management
2. Added an embedded Cocoa Touch framework (to share code with extensions)

**Issue**

Some libraries linked through CocoaPods having *"duplicated implementation"* across both the framework and app. This causes the app to crash when arbitrarily choosing an implementation to use in run-time.

This is apparently a bug within CocoaPods, as most of my dependencies link and run fine - only had issues with a few (Firebase, Fabric, AppsFlyerFramework).

---

I was [proposed](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6918#issuecomment-319447830)  a solution to try creating a post install hook to remove the double linking, but I am not sure how best to do approach this.

How can I easily remove dependency links from a specific target through the post install hook? I have seen some `post_install` hooks like this, but this removes a specific file whereas I need to remove the whole pod link.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'Pods-Earthlings'
            source_files = target.source_build_phase.files
            dummy = source_files.find do |file|
                file.file_ref.name == 'SomeDuplicate.m'
            end
            source_files.delete dummy
        end
    end
end
```